# Finding lowest values in dataset - postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working on a query where I pull a racer and three different race times associated with the racer.

```
select
   r.id,
   r.race1,
   r.race2,
   r.race3
from racer r
where r.race_id = 1
```

There are about 50 racers and each racer will have three different race time values `race1`, `race2` and `race3`. I am looking to add three more boolean values that indicate if they are the fastest time in each race.

```
select
   r.id,
   r.race1,
   -- race1_fastest,
   r.race2,
   --- race2_fastest,
   r.race3,
   --- race3_fastest,
from racer r
where r.race_id = 1
```

I have tried creating case statements using `min()` and a whole other table using `with` but am failing to get this working. Is there a standard method of comparing all the racers here? Or will I need to create a separate query?

Comment: Do you mean the fastest of *any* racer, or just fastest for the racer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the fastest times for each race, then join to it:

```sql
with fastest_times as (
    select
        race_id,
        min(race1) as race1_fastest,
        min(race2) as race2_fastest,
        min(race3) as race3_fastest
    from racer
    group by race_id
)
select
    r.id,
    race1,
    race1 = race1_fastest AS race1_fastest,
    race2,
    race2 = race2_fastest AS race2_fastest,
    race3,
    race3 = race3_fastest AS race3_fastest
from racer r
join fastest_times ft on ft.race_id = r.race_id
where r.race_id = 1
order by r.id
```

Not sure about which columns should be involved as you haven't shared your schema.

Also, the table name `racer` seems to be poorly named and should perhaps be `racer_times` or similar, and probably have foreign keys to `racer` and `race`.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres provides the scalar `LEAST` function which we can help here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LEAST(race1, race2, race3) AS fastest
    FROM racer
)

SELECT
    id,
    race1,
    race1 = fastest AS race1_fastest,
    race2,
    race2 = fastest AS race2_fastest,
    race3,
    race3 = fastest AS race3_fastest
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```